# T-SQL: ORDER BY 'Expression'

Tags: t-sql, sorting, dynamic-sql

All stored procedures which return data to the presentation layer of the webservice I am currently developing take as parameters two integers, `@StartingRow` and `@MaximumRows`, so that I can paginate results without retrieving the whole result list everytime. Now I would like to introduce sorting in these procedures, but from what I see everyone uses dynamic SQL to do the ordering:

```
EXEC ( 'WITH [Results] AS 
        ( SELECT * , 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ' + @SortExpression + @Direction + ')  AS 'RowNumber' 
          FROM [SomeTable] ) 
        SELECT [Column1] , [Column2] 
        WHERE ( [RowNumber] BETWEEN ' + @StartingRow + 
                          ' AND ( ' + @StartingRow + ' + ' + @MaximumRows + ' - 1) )' )
```

The problem with this approach is that I can't use dynamic SQL due to customer's demand, so that I can't specify the column according to which the results should be sorted. What are my options, then?

Comment: Easier to read, easier to help.  Reformat so we can read the entire SQL statement without needing to scroll.

Comment: You can't use dynamic SQL due to "customer's demand"? How/why is the *customer* placing demands on your *implementation*? Requirements/specifications should never be at that level...

Comment: Maybe the customer doesn’t trust the programmer to use dynamic SQL in a way that avoids the possibility of SQL injection. That would be a reasonable demand, given the sample of dynamic SQL posted here, which allows malicious code to be injected via the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case`.  This example sorts on `Col1` when `@SortParameter`equals 1. For parameter 5, it sorts by `Col2` in descending order.

```
order by
        case 
        when @SortParameter = 1 then Col1
        when @SortParameter = 2 then Col2
        ...
        end
,       case 
        when @SortParameter = 4 then Col1
        when @SortParameter = 5 then Col2
        ...
        end DESC
```

SQL Server cannot use indexes with this approach.  Which is the prime reason for using dynamic SQL instead.

Comment: It doesn't work... if col1 is first_name then it try to order by content of the first_name (of the first record), for instance my last name: ARIZA. but before, it try to convert to INT... it produces a mess up 'like'-> `ORDER BY CAST('ARIZA' as INT)` and you will get an exception `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ARIZA' to data type int.`. Option to solve this is create a column with the @SortParameter. so the CASE statement will be on the SELECT and then order by that new column.