# Trying to Use Sort Order from LINQ Query to Structure SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a LINQ query that sorts based on the following:

```
.OrderByDescending (l => l.foo == "ASDF")
.ThenByDescending (l => l.IsValid)
.ThenByDescending (l => l.Category == "X")
.ThenByDescending (l => l.Size)
.ThenByDescending (l => l.Description.Contains("Y")
.Thenby (l => l.ShelfNumber)
.Thenby (l => l.ItemNumber)
.ToList()
```

I'm sure there's possibly a better way to write that query, but my question is how am I able to write a SQL clause for a view that sorts in that fashion?

The ORDER BY clause, from what I've seen, doesn't allow you to base it off of any values, just columns.

Comment: You can order by expressions using case statements. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867824/t-sql-order-by-expression.

Comment: Assuming that's a LINQ to SQL query provider, simply look at the generated SQL for the query you've already written to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

To order based on a value in a SQL-Statement you can use the CASE Statement like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [YourTable]
ORDER BY
   (CASE
      WHEN [foo] = 'ASDF' THEN 1
      WHEN NOT ([foo] = 'ASDF') THEN 0
      ELSE NULL
    END) DESC
```

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is requiring me to use TOP or FOR XML or OFFSET:

SQL46047: The ORDER BY clause is not valid in views, inline functions, derived tables, sub-queries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FORXML or OFFSET is also specified.

Answer (score 0):

You could use more complex comparisons using an implementation of IComparer, for example:

My comparator class for an item:

```
private class MyComparer : IComparer<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    private readonly double extraData;

    public MyComparer(double extraData)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.extraData = extraData;
    }

    public int Compare(Tuple<int, int> x, Tuple<int, int> y)
    {
        if (extraData < 10)
            return x.Item1 - x.Item1;
        else
            return x.Item2 - x.Item2;
    }
}
```

And the code:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> collection = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
//Fill the list...
double extraData = 0.5d;
MyComparer comparer = new MyComparer(extraData);
collection.OrderByDescending(x => x, comparer);
```

The problem is if you want to use anonymous structures created in a previous LINQ you can not do in this way.